# How can I use this same Bubble sort layout to work on a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

The code below works to sort a singly linked list using class functions.It takes user input into an array, turns that array into a linked list, and then sorts it. I am uncertain on what changes I should make where to have it work for a Double Link List. I know the struct will need a new prev pointer but I don't know how to work that into the bubble
sort algorithm
This  code functions normally to bubble largest down, I'm not so much worried about efficiency right now as seeing the practicality of the sorting. The conversion to double link should only be a few new -> links as far as I am aware and I would like to see what those should be to better understand the fundamentals of bubble sorting and double linked list.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
 int val;
 Node* prev;
 Node* next;
 Node(int x){
  val = x;
  prev = NULL;
  next = NULL;
 }
};

class DoubleLink{
 public:
  Node* head;

 void push(int x){
  Node* newnode = new Node(x);
  newnode->next = head;
  if(head != NULL){
   head->prev = newnode;
  }
  head = newnode;
 }

 void printList(Node* head){
  Node* current = head;
  cout<<endl;
  while(current != NULL){
   cout<<current->val<<" ";
   current = current->next;
  }
 }

 int getSize(Node* headref){
  int count =0;
  while(headref != NULL){
   count++;
   headref = headref->next;
  }
  return count;
 }

 void bubbleSort(Node* headref){
 Node* lswap = NULL;
 int sz = getSize(headref);
 while(sz--){
  Node* current = headref;
  Node* prv = NULL;
  Node* cswap = NULL;
  while(current->next != lswap){
   Node* after = current->next;
   if(current->val > after->val){
    current->next = after->next;
    after->next = current;
    if(prv == NULL)
     current=after;
    else
     prv->next=after;

    prv=after;
    cswap = current;
    }
    else{
     prv = current;
     current=current->next;
    }
   }
   if(cswap==NULL)
    break;
   else
    lswap = cswap;
  }
 }
};

int main(){
 DoubleLink list;
 int size;
 cout<<"How many numbers"<<endl;
 cin>>size;
 int numbers[size];
 cout<<"Enter numbers"<<endl;
 for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
  cin>>numbers[i];
 }
 for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
  list.push(numbers[i]);
 }
 cout<<"first"<<endl;
 list.printList(list.head);
 cout<<"second"<<endl;
 list.bubbleSort(list.head);
 list.printList(list.head);
 cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You could cheat and just sort the double-linked list as if it were a single-linked list and then have an extra run-through of the sorted list to set the prev links correctly.

Comment: In general, a doubly linked list differs from a singly linked list by the addition of a link to the previous node.  I would believe that when you perform a *swap*, you also change the *previous* link fields.  *I could be wrong though, you'd have to test it out.*

Comment: Another possible cheat - instead of swapping pointers, swap values. Don't update pointers at all.